# How to stop Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS in sequelize sync

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to stop sequelize to drop tables this is making difficult for me adding dummy data again again whenever I restart server.

```
server running on port 3000
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `teams`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `teams`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teams` (`teamId` INTEGER auto_increment , `teamName` VARCHAR(255), `teamEmail` VARCHAR(255), `college` VARCHAR(255), `isPaid` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false, `isRone` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false, `isRtwo` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false, `isRthree` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false, `isNIT` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`teamId`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `teams` FROM `startupconclave`
Nice! Database looks fine
```

Answer (score 13):

Remove `{force: true}` from your `bin/www` script in `models.sequelize.sync()` method.